# Node.js: Inline JS expression not parsing

Tags: node.js

I am using NodeJS v16.14.2

I am a beginner and was trying to write a simple text with inline JS expressions embedded into a file. However, those expressions are not parsing:

Here's the code:

> ```
> ***const fs = require('fs');
> const textIn = fs.readFileSync('./txt/input.txt', 'utf-8');
> console.log(textIn);
> const textOut = 'This is what we know about avocados: ${textIn}. \nCreated on ${Date.now()}';
> fs.writeFileSync('./txt/output.txt', textOut);
> console.log('The file has been written');
> console.log(textOut);***
> ```

Here's the output:
The avocado  is popular in vegetarian cuisine as a substitute for meats in sandwiches and salads because of its high fat content 
The file has been written
This is what we know about avocado: ${textIn}.
Created on ${Date.now()}

Does this version not support expressions within strings? Should I use concatenate instead like in older versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment of `textOut` must be done with backticks ``. In this way the expressions inside `${...}` will be computed.

```
const textOut = `This is what we know about avocados: ${textIn}. \nCreated on ${Date.now()}`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to replace single quotes with Backtick(``) for textOut const

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).